# What's the proper way of updating ECS in terraform with blue/green deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-code-deploy

I have declared my ECS modules with the required IAM roles, application load balancer, auto scaling, and codedeploy with blue/green deployment.

Every time I update my task definition, or anything related to the ECS service, I get the error:

```
Error: updating ECS Service (arn:aws:ecs...): InvalidParameterException: Unable to update task definition on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.
```

I get it, I should use CodeDeploy to deploy, but it was declared there when I created the service, and set up everything, so I guess changing the code to declare it as a data source instead of a resource would be just a dirty quick fix.

What's the proper way of updating task definitions to prevent this error from happening?

Comment: You need to use `lifecycle` blocks with `ignore_changes` for that to work. However, since there is no code, it's hard to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your cluster definition set lifecycle policies as suggested by [Marko E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343484/marko-e)

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "this" {
      ...
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
          task_definition,
          load_balancer,
          network_configuration
    ]
}
```

and then you can `terraform apply` new task definitions, but you then need to deploy by updating your appspec.yaml file to point to the new task definition and running a codedeploy deployment.

```
 Resources:
   - TargetService:
       Type: AWS::ECS::Service
       Properties:
          TaskDefinition: "[Your task definition arn]"
```

See template appspec.yaml file [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codedeploy-appspec-assistant/blob/master/ecs-default-appspec-template-uncommented.yml)